# Is it possible to first copy the files, then show a custom dialog and then run a custom action in a WiX installer?

Tags: wix, installation

I want the following behavior in a WiX installer:

- a "read and accept EULA" dialog is displayed
- a "select folder" dialog is displayed
- files are copied to the target folder
- a custom dialog is displayed requiring some action from the user and entering a specific string of characters into an edit box on the custom dialog
- a custom action runs an executable from inside the target folder and passes the string entered into the custom dialog

... and no, the string which is entered into the custom dialog is not known until the files are copied and the user does the action required from him.

I've searched quite a lot and it looks like there's a "UI sequence" which shows dialogs in certain order and there's an "Execute sequence" which copies files and runs custom action. And it looks like I cannot interleave them.

Is the sequence I described above even possible?

Comment: Can you do this on application launch instead?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Yes, but it'd be cleaner if this was part of the installation.